# Uploading a pdf file to Document Set programmatically using FileUpload

Tags: file-upload, document-set

I am trying to upload a pdf file to a Document set using following code, but it generates this error `File contains corrupted data.` when it comes to the last line of the code

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderMain");
FileUpload fileUpload = (FileUpload)cph.FindControl("AddPdfFileUpload");

if (fileUpload.HasFile)
{
    DocumentSet documentSet = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(ListItem.Folder);

    byte[] pdfBytes = fileUpload.FileBytes;


    SPContentTypeId contentTypeId = List.ContentTypes["TemplateCT"].Id;

    string documentSetName = ListItem.Name;
    SPFolder targetFolder = List.RootFolder;
    Hashtable properties = ListItem.Properties;
    DocumentSet newDocSet = DocumentSet.Import(pdfBytes, documentSetName, targetFolder, contentTypeId, properties, CurrentWeb.CurrentUser);

}
```

I need to retrieve the FileUpload using above code because it has been added programmatically. I have debugged the code and the pdfBytes contains data and isn't empty.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading to SharePoint I would suggest doing it like this instead.

```
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(documentPath);
SPFile file = documentLibrary.Files.Add(destinationSiteUrl + "/" + documentName, fileStream);
documentLibrary.Update();
```

Note that the Add method has more input parameters (Override methods). But works great for all types of files if you use a FileStream.

`SPFile file` is there if you want to get the ListItem later to add metadata... use the id (file.Item.ID)

Also **worth mentioning** is that you have to update the library to complete the upload.

Edit: Upload to SharePoint Document set.

- Get the SPFolder from the document set.
- Use a file stream or byte array etc. to hold the information of the document.
- Then use the destination with filename(with extention (.pdf))

Code:

```
byte[] pdfBytes = fileUpload.FileBytes; 
SPFolder dsFolder = documentSet.Folder; 
dsFolder.Files.Add(dsFolder.Url + "/" + fileName, pdfBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks I have solved the problem but not using this metod. this is the solution
byte[] pdfBytes = fileUpload.FileBytes;
SPFolder dsFolder = documentSet.Folder; dsFolder.Files.Add(dsFolder.Url + "/" + fileName, pdfBytes);

Comment: You used dsFiles.Files.Add so you used the method i answered with ;)